# Parsing text file and comparing values

Tags: c++, while-loop, istringstream

Let's say I have a text file in a format like like this...

```
Compton, Calif., 2123, 12
Denver, CO., 3443, 23
Houston, Texas, 3838, 13
Atlanta, GA., 9483, 93
```

I want to compare the values in the 3rd column and 4th column against each other to check for the highest then use that to print out the value and the corresponding city. How can I fix this while loop to properly do so?

```
string city[10];
string state[10];
string lines;
int pop[20];
int ele[20];
int counter = 0;
int a = 0;

while(getline(inputfile, lines)){
    istringstream iss(lines);
    getline(iss, city[a], ',');
    getline(iss, state[a], ',');
    getline(iss, lines, ',');
    pop[a] = stoi(lines);
    getline(iss, lines, ',');
    ele[a] = stoi(lines);
    a++;
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: The best method is to create a structure (or class) to model one record (row/line).  Read in each record.  Ignore the columns you don't need.  Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file csv ignore column".

Comment: Whenever you call a read operation like getline()  you must check its return value and write code to handle any read error.

Comment: Note that "handle any read error" can be as simple as scream and fall down, just so long as you know the program screamed and fell down. Bonus points for leaving some breadcrumbs like a log message or two explaining why the program screamed and fell down so you can debug more effectively.